# intermittent exception while working with parallel for

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, task-parallel-library

I'm currently running a simple peace of code that renders a partial view and adds the result to a ConcurrentBag:

```
Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, Model.Count,
                                Sub(i)
                                    carXmls.Add(Html.Partial("PublisherVehicleXml16", Model(i)))
                                End Sub)
```

The sad thing is that every once in a while this thing crashes with the following exception: `Stack empty.`

This happens intermittently and only on our staging and production environments. Any ideas where this might be coming from?

**Edit:** carsXmls is declared like this:

```
   Dim carXmls As New Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag(Of MvcHtmlString)
```

and the full exception is:

> **Message** Stack empty.
>
> **Source** System
>
> **Target site** T Pop()
>
> **Stack trace**
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.b__19()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)

Comment: What's the type of the `carXmls` variable?

Comment: Could you post the full exception including its stack trace?

Comment: I've edited the question to provide more info

Comment: Given the stack trace should [asp.net-mvc] be added as a tag? Or is [razor] enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running code on multiple threads which is using ASP.NET objects. ASP.NET (MVC) does not guarantee you that this is safe. And as you can see, it is unsafe.

In short, you cannot use the ASP.NET infrastructure concurrently.

I suggest that you extract all heavy computations so that you can paralleled them without using ASP.NET objects. You can then render the views sequentially.